# Create a loop to generate a new "user" with own variable names if user makes number of users = 2, or 3, etc

Tags: java, arrays, loops, char, joptionpane

You don't have to read all my code, don't worry. My main problem is highlighted in the body of this message.

I am very new to programming. I'm supposed to create a Java program that reads a string input, separates that string into chars mapped to an array (that array is a Memo for answers to multiple choice Questions). Then read another string input from user, separate that input into chars in an array as well, and then compare the two array indices. basically, it's supposed to see how many array indices are the same, and then generate a score of correct answers (it's a multiple choice answer program, so the chars in the strings will be A B or C).

I have to store the student's (user's) name and keep his score. But the program will ask you for how many students there are and then run a loop asking of name, and answer (as many times as the amount of students you typed in. Max is 10), then compare the answer to the memo, generate a score, and use all the students answers to calculator an average score. So far I have managed to create a program that will do this for one user. The problem I have is looping it to store multiple user names, and scores, to calculate an average score.

Here is my code. if you copy and paste this into your IDE, you'll see that it runs perfectly (apart from some error handling and `JOptionPane` dialog button stuff left out). But it will only work IF you enter the number of users as 1. Anything else, and it won't run properly. So how do I get it to loop for several users?

```
package multiquestions;

import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class MultiQuestions {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    String aMemo = getInput0();
    int aStudentNumber = getInput1();
    String aStudentName = getInput2();
    String aStudentAnswer = getInput3();
    int aScore = CalcScore(aStudentAnswer, aMemo);
    if (aStudentNumber == 1) {
      StudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore);
    }
    System.exit(0);
  }
  public static String getInput0() {
    String Memo = JOptionPane
        .showInputDialog("Please enter the memo answers to the 10 multiple choice questions\nno spaces and all in Capital letters e.g.ABCDEABCDE");
    return Memo;
  }
  public static int getInput1() {
    int StudentNumber = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane
        .showInputDialog("Please enter the number of students in the class"));
    return StudentNumber;
  }
  public static String getInput2() {
    String StudentName = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the student's name");
    return StudentName;
  }
  public static String getInput3() {
    String StudentAnswer = JOptionPane
        .showInputDialog("Please enter the student's answers to the 10 multiple choice questions\nno spaces and all in Capital letters e.g.ABCDEABCDE");
    return StudentAnswer;
  }
  public static int CalcScore(String bStudentAnswer, String bMemo) {
    int One;
    int Two;
    int Three;
    int Four;
    int Five;
    int Six;
    int Seven;
    int Eight;
    int Nine;
    int Ten;
    char Reference[] = new char[10];
    for (char Ref : Reference) {
      Reference[0] = bMemo.charAt(0);
      Reference[1] = bMemo.charAt(1);
      Reference[2] = bMemo.charAt(2);
      Reference[3] = bMemo.charAt(3);
      Reference[4] = bMemo.charAt(4);
      Reference[5] = bMemo.charAt(5);
      Reference[6] = bMemo.charAt(6);
      Reference[7] = bMemo.charAt(7);
      Reference[8] = bMemo.charAt(8);
      Reference[9] = bMemo.charAt(9);
    }
    char Answer[] = new char[10];
    for (char Ans : Answer) {
      Answer[0] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(0);
      Answer[1] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(1);
      Answer[2] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(2);
      Answer[3] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(3);
      Answer[4] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(4);
      Answer[5] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(5);
      Answer[6] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(6);
      Answer[7] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(7);
      Answer[8] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(8);
      Answer[9] = bStudentAnswer.charAt(9);
    }
    /*
     * Below is the list of if statements which add one to each variable (Variables One to Ten
     * declared at top of this method) if the array characters match each other at their indeces
     */
    if (Reference[0] == Answer[0]) {
      One = 1;
    } else {
      One = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[1] == Answer[1]) {
      Two = 1;
    } else {
      Two = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[2] == Answer[2]) {
      Three = 1;
    } else {
      Three = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[3] == Answer[3]) {
      Four = 1;
    } else {
      Four = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[4] == Answer[4]) {
      Five = 1;
    } else {
      Five = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[5] == Answer[5]) {
      Six = 1;
    } else {
      Six = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[6] == Answer[6]) {
      Seven = 1;
    } else {
      Seven = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[7] == Answer[7]) {
      Eight = 1;
    } else {
      Eight = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[8] == Answer[8]) {
      Nine = 1;
    } else {
      Nine = 0;
    }
    if (Reference[9] == Answer[9]) {
      Ten = 1;
    } else {
      Ten = 0;
    }
    int Score = One + Two + Three + Four + Five + Six + Seven + Eight + Nine + Ten;
    return Score;
  }
  public static void StudentInfo(String bStudentName, int bScore) {
    switch (bScore) {
    /*
     * Below is case stament for values of bScore(score returned from CalcScore() For each value of
     * bScore it must do something specific
     */
    case 10:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     A     Marvelous");
      break;
    case 9:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     A     Marvelous");
      break;
    case 8:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     B     Outstanding");
      break;
    case 7:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     C     Significant");
      break;
    case 6:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore
          + "/10     D     Above Average");
      break;
    case 5:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore
          + "/10     E     Barely Adequate");
      break;
    case 4:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     F     Fail");
      break;
    case 3:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     F     Fail");
      break;
    case 2:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     F     Fail");
      break;
    case 1:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     F     Fail");
      break;
    case 0:
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, bStudentName + "     " + bScore + "/10     F     Fail");
    }
  }
  public static void Exit() {
    int exit = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure you want to exit?");
    if (exit == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
      System.exit(0);
    }
  }
  public static void CalcAverage() {}
}
```

Comment: You might want to look into the method `String.toCharArray()`

Comment: "*I am very very very very very new to programming*" - Not new enough.. :D

Comment: *"stuff left out"*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

instead of saying if == 1, do

```
for (int i = 0; i < aStudentNumber; i++) {
  String aStudentName = getInput2();
  String aStudentAnswer = getInput3();
  int aScore = CalcScore(aStudentAnswer, aMemo);

  StudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore);
}
```

Now, if you want to store that data programmatically so you can access it later on, change your StudentInfo method to something like

```
public static StudentInfo createStudentInfo(String bStudentName, int bScore){
  ...
  return someObj;
}
```

where `someObj` is a an instance of a StudentInfo class (that you have to create) that actually holds all of the data you want to keep track of.  Then, simply add that class to a list (inside your loop):

```
ArrayList<StudentInfo> siList = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>();

for (int i = 0; i < aStudentNumber; i++) {
    String aStudentName = getInput2();
    String aStudentAnswer = getInput3();
    int aScore = CalcScore(aStudentAnswer, aMemo);

    //StudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore); // get rid of this line since we are adding it to a list now
    siList.add(createStudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore));
}
```

Now you can recall all of that data if need be.

The biggest thing is that you need a loop.  Loop until the index is at your count, and perform the same actions for each answer set.

Edit: The following is to address the question posted in the comments.

I think you're better off with a constructor.  Use a class something like this:

```
public class StudentInfo {

    private String bStudentName;
    private int bScore;

    public StudentInfo (String bStudentName, int bScore) {
        this.bStudentName = bStudentName;
        this.bScore = bScore;
    }

    public String getStudentName() {
        return this.bStudentName; //'this' keyword not really necessary, but helpful
    }

    public int getScore() {
        return this.bScore;// again, 'this' not necessary
    }

    public void doStuff() { // optional method to do stuff with the data if need be
        ...
    }
}
```

Then, in your loop, do

```
ArrayList<StudentInfo> siList = new ArrayList<StudentInfo>();
for (int i = 0; i < aStudentNumber; i++) {
    String aStudentName = getInput2();
    String aStudentAnswer = getInput3();
    int aScore = CalcScore(aStudentAnswer, aMemo);

    //StudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore); // get rid of this line since we are adding it to a list now
    //siList.add(createStudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore));
    StudentInfo si = new StudentInfo(aStudentName, aScore);
    si.doStuff(); // optional method call in case you want to do something with the data other than store it.
    siList.add(si);
}
```

your `StudentInfo` class should be in the same package as your main class.  If, for some reason, it is not, at the top of your main class add `include theotherpackage.StudentInfo;`

Comment: Thanks, I've created a class called StudentInfo and within it, created a Student_Info method:

public void Student_Info(String bStudentName, int bScore) {

Inside, I've put the same code that the StudentInfo method (as seen in my question) has. But how do I get my main class to see the StudentInfo class, and how do I get my StudentInfo class to allow itself to be called by main?

Comment: @UrbanChaos2.0: see my updated answer.  I think it answers your question.  If not, rephrase and I'll try again.

Comment: I've put your code in, and have no issue, apart from two. Firtly, the "siList.add(siList);" line has a red line through it. And actually don't know how to return the StudentInfo Class instance in the createStudentInfo method. Also, once I am able to store all the calculated scores, how do I use each score value?

Comment: @UrbanChaos2.0 Apologies.  I mistyped the siList.add function.  I've updated my answer.  As for the class instance: my code above uses a constructor.  It's essentially a method that is run right when you instantiate a new class.  It ALSO saves you from having to do just what you are worried about: getting back a class instance.  The ctor sets up all your variables.  If you use my code, `StudentInfo si` is the returned instance.

Comment: @UrbanChaos2.0 As for the scores, use the "getter" method: `si.getScore` will return the calculated score for that particular StudentInfo object.  If you want the individual scores, then you will have to modify the constructor and save them individually.

Answer (score 0):

Might be helpful for learning purpose (assuming strings are not null and lengths of strings are equal):

```
public static int CalcScore(String bStudentAnswer, String bMemo) {
    char[] answer = bStudentAnswer.toCharArray();
    char[] memo = bMemo.toCharArray();
    int score = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < answer.length; i++) {
        if (answer[i] == memo[i]) score++;
    }
    return score;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, you've helped simplify my method a lot.